# Getting Error In The when/otherwise clause

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to create a new column in dataframe based on three other columns data. The below code I have written for the same

```
dataFrame.withColumn('net_inventory_qty', when((dataFrame.raw_wip_fg_indicator =='RAW MATERIALS') |
                        (dataFrame.raw_wip_fg_indicator =='WIP') |
                        (dataFrame.raw_wip_fg_indicator =='FINISHED GOODS'), dataFrame.total_stock_qty+dataFrame.sit_qty).
                        otherwise(dataFrame.sit_qty))
```

But when I run the Glue Job it is throwing error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '(`total_stock_qty` + `sit_qty`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`total_stock_qty` + `sit_qty`)' (struct<double:double,string:string> and double)
```

What am I missing? Any suggestion will help

Comment: I am getting this while running Glue Job and the code is in pyspark

Comment: Please add the output of `dataFrame.printSchema()` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because check your schema, according to error message, I can guest 2 columns following with their type:

```
total_stock_qty: struct<double:double,string:string>
sit_qty: double
```

You can printSchema() or show() to check data first